# Data from many workbook in vba - invalid qualifier

Tags: excel, vba

I try to get data from many workbook in same cell, but I get invalid qualifier error

```
Dim obj() As Workbook
Dim total As Integer

total = 0
Set obj(1) = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Riky\Downloads\Compressed\2020\BAGUNUNG\02.06.20\DIANA")
Set obj(2) = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Riky\Downloads\Compressed\2020\BAGUNUNG\02.06.20\GULTOM")
Set obj(3) = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Riky\Downloads\Compressed\2020\BAGUNUNG\02.06.20\HSR")
Set obj(4) = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Riky\Downloads\Compressed\2020\BAGUNUNG\02.06.20\MADI")

total = total + obj(1).Worksheets(1).Cells(33, 5) + obj(2).Worksheets(1).Cells(33, 5) + 
obj(3).Worksheets(1).Cells(33, 5) + obj(4).Worksheets(1).Cells(33, 5)
Cells(1, 1) = total

obj.Close
```

Can someone help?

Comment: You've declared obj to be array (of workbooks) ... therefore you cannot use obj.close. You must obj(0).close ... etc.

Comment: @TechnoDabbler still not work , i get Subscript out of range :(

Comment: You are missing a space and an underscore ` _` as a line break after the `+` sign. After that you have to share where you want to write the result because it will write it to `obj(4)`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

`obj.Close`

with:

```
obj(1).Close
obj(2).Close
obj(3).Close
obj(4).Close
```

Answer (score 1):

### Sum of Cells (Multiple Workbooks)

- Copy both codes into a standard module e.g `Module1`.
- Run the `Sub` only, the `Function` is being called.
- Adjust the **const**ants in both procedures.
- It is assumed that the result will be written to `ThisWorkbook`, the
  workbook containing this code.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Function getTotal(Optional ByVal aDate As Date) As Double

    Const wsName As Variant = 1 ' can also be e.g. "Sheet1"
    Const Address As String = "E33"
    Const Extension As String = ".xlsx"
    Dim pPeople() As Variant: pPeople = Array("DIANA", "GULTOM", "HSR", "MADI")
    Dim pFirst As String
    pFirst = "C:\Users\Riky\Downloads\Compressed\2020\BAGUNUNG"

    Dim pDate As String: pDate = Format(aDate, "dd.mm.yy")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, i As Long, Total As Double, wbPath As String
    For i = 0 To UBound(pPeople)
        wbPath = pFirst & Application.PathSeparator & pDate _
               & Application.PathSeparator & pPeople(i) & Extension
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbPath)
        Total = Total + wb.Worksheets(wsName).Range(Address).Value
        wb.Close False
    Next
    
    getTotal = Total
    
End Function

' e.g.:
Sub TodaysTotal()
    
    Const wsName As Variant = "Sheet1"
    Const Address As String = "A1"
    
    Dim Total As Double, aDate As Date
    aDate = DateSerial(2020, 7, 2)
    Total = getTotal(aDate)

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName).Range(Address) = Total

End Sub
```